# SSAS Tabular Model Filtering a Measure with DAX Based on Selection in Model

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

I'm trying to use DAX in a Measure or Expression within an SSAS Tabular Model.

When I try this in DAX it works okay:

```
Measure:=calculate(SUM(table1[Amount]),
filter(dim_TableDesc,dim_Category[Category_Nm]="Sales"),
filter(table1,table1[DateKey] >= 19000101 && table1[DateKey] <=20221231))
```

When I view within SSMS and browse the cube, the measure changes okay when I select 2016 or 2017 based on a date hierarchy I've setup.

However how do I make this part dynamic based on the selection in the cube browser:

```
filter(table1,table1[DateKey] >= 19000101 && table1[DateKey] <=20221231))?
```

I would like to change the last part of this calculation to the date selected in the Cube then calculate backwards:

```
  && table1[DateKey] <=20221231))
```

For instance the 19000101 date needs to be 3 months prior to the end date of 20221231 in other measures, which should be dynamic.

If the date selected in the cube browser is 20221130, then use this date as the filter then go back 3M prior on the first of the month and so forth...using the BETWEEN logic.

I tried using SUMMARIZECOLUMN or SUMMARIZE in the second part of the BETWEEN query and it's giving me an error.

Comment: You can examine the visible dates in filter context in the measure. 
 See https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-the-difference-between-lastdate-and-max-in-dax/

Comment: Thanks David!  I read the article and still can't figure out using LASTDATE, MAX functions in the DAX to get the answer I'm looking for...the last date in the DAX query above has to be dynamic and changes based on input and I can't figure that part out yet...

Comment: Why are you using SSMS to view the data? Use Power BI Desktop and set the dates with a Slicer.